# Strange permissions on directory created by mkdir (no execution)

Tags: linux, perl, cron, centos6

I have this old Perl script. This script is working from cron on CentOS 6.4. It creates a temporary directory and is trying to unzip files there.

This is a piece of code:

```
$lg->li("Creating Directory... \n\t$unzip_dir");
mkdir ($unzip_dir, 0777) or my_die("mkdir $unzip_dir failed") unless (-e $unzip_dir && -d $unzip_dir);
```

However after execution the directory has weird permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x 42 buser     agroup  12K Dec 30 09:18 .
drwxrwsr-x  4 buser     agroup 4.0K Apr  6  2012 ..
drw-rwSr--  2 auser     agroup 4.0K Dec 28 11:51 tm_unpack_dir_1388412502.20184
```

The umask for user auser is a 0002.

Why the new directory has no execution permission? Any idea, how this can happen?

Comment: That umask would not produce those permissions. Did you try [codnodder's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20842844/176646) to print the umask? Also note that the umask can be changed for *this process* by calling `umask EXPR` in the script.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes I did. The reply from script was 0002. The script has no explicit 'umask' call inside.

Comment: And I assume you ran it like `su - auser -c 'perl ...'`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot No, from the cron. I have no permissions for su.

Comment: And you get the same permissions if you run this from cron: `perl -e 'mkdir "/path/to/dir"'`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I can't reproduce result. Even the script not always creates such strange directories. Most of the time it works fine.

Comment: You should have said that in your question. If this is an intermittent problem, something else is going on (obviously). Perhaps you're calling `chmod` later in the script, or another script is changing the permissions after the directories are created. The information you have provided is not enough to debug your issue, so you'll need to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Do you have any idea what to add to the debugging output except umask and permissions?

Comment: Like I said, something else must be going on. It could even be in a completely different script. Since this is an intermittent problem, you will need to figure out what is common between failures. Do the permissions only get dorked at certain times or certain days of the week? After reboots? When unicorns sprinkle fairy dust on your cubicle? I'm not familiar with your setup so I can't say more than that, except that a umask of 0002 + `mkdir` alone do *not* cause those permissions (as you saw for yourself).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot finally unicorns sprinkle fairy dust on my cubicle.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you found the source of your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The weird permissions are caused by the setgid bit on the parent directory in combination with an unusual umask:

Look at the permissions of the parent directory, the first line:

```
drwxrwsr-x 42 buser     agroup  12K Dec 30 09:18 .
drw-rwSr--  2 auser     agroup 4.0K Dec 28 11:51 tm_unpack_dir_1388412502.20184
```

Notice it has `rwxrwsr-x` which means that the setgid bit is set. The setgid bit on a directory causes new files in the directory to be created with the same group as the directory. New directories [inherit the setgid bit from their parent](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html).

A umask of `0113` will cause the strange permissions you're seeing. That is an unusual umask, the default is `0022`. The umask is set in the environment executing the script, or directly in the script itself.

Don't worry about `0777` after `mkdir` in your script: `mkdir $dir, 0777` means *"create $dir without interfering with the present umask"*. `0777` [is the default and can be safely omitted](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html).

Try [setting the umask](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html) directly in your script:

```
umask 0022;
$lg->li("Creating Directory... \n\t$unzip_dir");
mkdir ($unzip_dir) or my_die("mkdir $unzip_dir failed") unless (-e $unzip_dir && -d $unzip_dir);
```

should cause:

```
drwxrwsr-x 42 buser     agroup  12K Dec 30 09:18 .
drwxr-sr-x  2 auser     agroup 4.0K Dec 28 11:51 tm_unpack_dir_1388412502.20184
```

New directory permissions are `rwxr-sr-x` which is more normal. Notice that the setgid bit is still set because of the parent directory.

Oh, you might wonder why the setgid bit is sometimes lowercase `'s'` and sometimes uppercase `'S'`. That depends on the `executable bit`. Lowercase `s` means the `executable bit` is set, uppercase means it's not set:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 johan johan 4096 Dec 30 17:22 foo
$ chmod g+s foo
$ ls -l 
drwxr-sr-x 2 johan johan 4096 Dec 30 17:22 foo
$ chmod g-x foo
$ ls -l 
drwxr-Sr-x 2 johan johan 4096 Dec 30 17:22 foo
```

Comment: actually, the umask for this user is 0002.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct to me.

Confirming on my system:

```
perl -e 'mkdir("foo", 0777);'

drwxr-xr-x  2 user  user     512 Dec 30 10:48 foo
```

[mkdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) is affected by your [umask](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html). A funky umask can do funky things.

What does this yield for you?

```
perl -e 'printf("%04o\n", umask());'
```

I get this:

```
0022
```

Which is why my folder is created 0755 when I ask for 0777.

Comment: @alex What are the permissions of the parent directory?

Comment: The permission for the parent directory are: drwxrwsr-x

Answer (score 1):

I've debugged script and found source of the problem.
The problem caused by tar.gz archive sent to us by one of our submitters. These tar files having directory without execution permission set. I have no idea how they achieve such result.

One more problem - the Gnu Tar have no key to prevent restoring files and directories permissions.

So after extracting archive with wrong permissions I have to recursively set right permissions on the all files and directories in the archive.

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the setuid and setgid bits have been set.

The setuid (set user id) is a permission bit, that allows the users to exec a program with the permissions of its owner.

The setgid (set group id) is a bit that allows the user to exec a program with the permissions of the group owner.

http://linuxg.net/how-to-set-the-setuid-and-setgid-bit-for-files-in-linux-and-unix/

Comment: Who set these bits? The function mkdir ($unzip_dir, 0777) definitely set permission as 0777.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The question is about directories, not files. setuid and setgid for directories have [a different meaning](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html)